# How would I refresh a page when I close a modal?

Tags: javascript

I've got a video playing in a modal, but when I close the modal the video continues to play in the background (and sound continues.) The modal opens with #modal added to the URL, and when it closes it links to #refresh. Why isn't this code refreshing the page when #refresh is loaded?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("refresh") > -1) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "products.html";
  },1000);
}

<a href="#refresh"><img src="images/x.jpg"><meta http-equiv="refresh"></a>
```

When returning to #refresh, the page itself isn't refreshed, so this function cannot trigger until the user refreshes the page.

Comment: it needs to be in an event handler listening for the button to be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('refresh').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.reload;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some reason @Carl Edwards

Answer (score 0):

First of all to look for a hash use window.location.hash so something like:

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("refresh") > -1) {
```

and the to refresh use window.location.href so:

```
window.location.href = "products.html";
```